# SELECT range of integers in MySQL. Eg. 1,2,3,4,...,n;

Tags: mysql, range, sequence

I need to select range of integer in MySQL. Something like this

`SELECT RANGE(10,20) AS range;`

returns

`10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ..., 20`

**Why?**
I would like to select random phone number from range which is not yet registered. This is idea.

`SELECT RANGE(100000,999999) AS range FROM phone WHERE phoneNum <> range LIMIT FLOOR(100000 + RAND()*(899999);`

Comment: Why not do it within the program that is making use of the SQL queries?

Comment: Does it always need to return one phonenumber or do you want to be able to select 1000 new phonenumbers at once? And do you somewhere have a table of "already-given-out" phonenumbers?

Answer (score 10):

Problems with your query:

1. You can't use `range` in the WHERE clause. It is an alias and will only be defined after the WHERE clause is performed.
2. Even if you could use it, it makes no sense to compare a number with a set of numbers using `<>`. In general you could use `IN(...)`, but in you particular case you should use `BETWEEN 100000 and 999999` and avoid the need for a `RANGE` function.
3. If you only want one number then the limit should be 1, not something random. Usually to select random items you use `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Try using this query:

```
SELECT phoneNum, 100000 as rangeStart, 999999 AS rangeEnd
FROM phone
WHERE phoneNum NOT BETWEEN 100000 AND 999999
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

---

If you want to find a number not in your table and the available numbers are not close to depletion (say less than 80% are assigned) a good approach would be to generate random numbers and check if they are assigned until you find one that isn't.

*A pure MySQL solution may exists but I think it needs some twisted joins, random and modulus.*

Comment: Won't that query return an existing phone number? He wants to return a random value in the range that does not exist in the table, i.e. `SELECT number FROM RANGE(100000,999999) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT phoneNum FROM phone WHERE phoneNum = number) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` - if `RANGE` generated a table of numbers on the fly

Comment: @Rup Now that you say it, it does make sense. I didn't understand the requirement until now.

Comment: @Rup I don't think it would be very efficient to generate those kind of tables on the fly.

Comment: Sure - I didn't expect it'd actually generate a full temporary talbe of numbers, I assumed that would get optimised away somehow.

Comment: @Rup I posted another answer that uses a permanent table of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

First of all create a table with just numbers that has all the numbers from 1 to MAX_NUM.

Then use this query:

```
SELECT n.id as newNumber
FROM numbers AS n
LEFT JOIN phone AS p
    ON p.phoneNum = n.id
WHERE 
    p.phoneNum IS NULL AND
    n.id BETWEEN lowerLimit AND upperLIMIT    
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

This way you can also get multiple number relatively fast by changing the limit value.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the MariaDB SEQUENCE engine can do this for you:

```
SELECT `seq` FROM `seq_1234_to_5678`;
```